# How can I take user input and write it to a Text file?

Tags: python, file-io

This is my code:

```
def student_info(name,age,gender):
    print("The student name is:",name)
    print("The student age is:",age)
    print("The student gender is:",gender)
print("*"*70)
Student_name=input("Enter Student name:")
Student_age=input("Enter Student age:")
Student_gender=input("Enter Student gender:")


print("*"*70)

with open('Try1.txt', 'w') as f:
    student_info(Student_name,Student_age,Student_gender)

f.write((Student_name,Student_age,Student_gender)
```

I try to write the user inputs into a text file but the code doesn't work. I don't know why. Help, please.

Comment: write takes a single str type argument not a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

1. You try to pass a tuple to write, write only takes a single str type argument so you need to change that.
2. The f.write should be in the with statement. student_info, on the other hand, should be outside the with statement.

So your code should look something like this:

```
with open('Try1.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(Student_name+" "+Student_age+" "+Student_gender)

student_info(Student_name,Student_age,Student_gender)
```

Be aware, your programme overrides everything that is already in the file.